# "goto" behavior in C : how symbols are handled?

Tags: c, symbols, goto

I was wondering, in the following code :

```
{
    int i = 42;
    goto end;
}
end:
```

What is the status of the symbol **i** when we reach **end:** (what would we see in a debugger) ? Does it still exist, even if we're out of the scope ? Is there a standard behavior or is it compiler-dependent ?

For the sake of the example, let's assume that the code is compiled using gcc with debug symbols.

Subsidiarily, is the behavior the same in C++ ?

Thank you.

Comment: What stops you from executing this code? You could even compile it with different optimization flags or different gcc versions..

Comment: If you left scope - all local are destroyed. And it doesn't matter in what way scope was left.

Comment: @aisbaa How would executing this code help to answer the question?

Comment: @CompuChip it would answer "(what would we see in a debugger)" part, assuming execution is under debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A variable that has been declared in a block will "live" only in that block (it does not matter if you used goto or not).

This behavior is the same in c++

Comment: So I assume that in C++, RAII would apply and destroyers would be called, right ?

Comment: Yes , except on primitive types though

Answer (score 3):

The status is... invisible (out of scope).